# iOS 10 Message Extension app: How can I get the MSSticker created by this function?

Tags: swift, ios10

I found this repo on github that enables you to create an animated MSSticker from images:

https://github.com/radif/MSSticker-Images

Once I have called:

```
let sticker = MSSticker(images: images, frameDelay: 1.0/14.0, numberOfLoops: 0, localizedDescription: "generated sticker")
```

How do I make the sticker appear in the view or the text bar? I can't add it as a subview to my view, so how do I show it?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the GitHub link you provided it seems like a look at the [Apple Documentation about MSSticker](https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msstickerview) should help. And if I am not mistaken that GitHub repo is just helping you create an MSSticker from an array of UIImages. Try this out:

```
 let yourSticker = MSSticker(images: images, frameDelay: 1.0/14.0, numberOfLoops: 0, localizedDescription: "generated sticker")
 // stickerView is an MSStickerView, which inherits from UIView
 let stickerView = init(CGRect(...), sticker: yourSticker)
 yourView.addSubview(stickerView)
```