# Create MSSticker from UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, imessage

How do I create an MSSticker from a UIImage? The only initializer for an MSSticker is from a local URL, which makes me believe that I first must write the UIImage to a file. If that's the case, could someone explain how to do this because I have had trouble doing so. I was successfully able to write to a file using `NSData.writeToFile()`, but I could not figure out what URL to pass to the MSSticker initializer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a solution readily available in this other thread: [iOS 10 Message Extension app: How can I get the MSSticker created by this function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094981/ios-10-message-extension-app-how-can-i-get-the-mssticker-created-by-this-functi)

The idea is the same you mention in your question: save the images to disk, and then load the MSSticker instance from them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create MSSticker using UIImage , first you need to put resources in bundle not is assets.xcassets folder. after that just use this simple method to create sticker object.

```
        let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: imgName, ofType: ".png")

        let pathurl =  URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath!)

        do {
            try cell.stickerview.sticker = MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: pathurl, localizedDescription: "anything that you want")

        }
        catch {
            fatalError("Failed to create sticker: \(error)")
        }
```